# React Router's match param appears and then disappears with form submission call

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router-v4

I'm using React, React Router, Firebase, and Semantic UI React Components. Upon the initial rendering of my route's component, the parameter 'church_id' is present when I console.log 'this.props' - as it should be. However, after clicking the 'Add' button to submit the form, I receive an error:

[Cannot read property match of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp2UL.png)

It is as if the 'this.props.match.params.church_id' disappears. Is this due to an additional re-rendering of the component after the form submission? I'm using 'e.preventDefault()' to prevent a re-rendering, so I'm not exactly sure how to proceed. Any help would be amazingly appreciated!

Here is the component rendering the form:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Grid, Message, Button,
  Segment, Container, Header,
  Form
} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import database from '../../firebase/firebase';


export default class AddDriverPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      seatsAvailable: ''
    };

    this.onFirstNameChange = this.onFirstNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onLastNameChange = this.onLastNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onSeatsAvailable = this.onSeatsAvailable.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onFirstNameChange(e) {
    const firstName = e.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({ firstName }));
  }

  onLastNameChange(e) {
    const lastName = e.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({ lastName }));
  }

  onSeatsAvailable(e) {
    const seatsAvailable = e.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({ seatsAvailable }));
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const church_id = this.props.match.params.church_id;
    const driversRefString = `churches/${church_id}/drivers`;
    const driversRef = database.ref(driversRefString);
    const driver = {
      firstName: this.state.firstName.trim(),
      lastName: this.state.lastName.trim(),
      seatsAvailable: this.state.seatsAvailable.trim()
    };
    driversRef.push(driver);
    this.setState(() => ({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      seatsAvailable: ''
    }));
    this.props.history.push(`/drivers/${church_id}`);
    if (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    console.log(this.props.match.params.church_id, 'submitted');
  }

  render() {
    console.log('state:', this.state, 'props:', this.props, 'AddDriverPage');
    // console.log(this.props.match.params.church_id);

    return (
      <Grid>

        {/* Row */}
        <Grid.Row centered={true}>
          <Grid.Column width={14}>
            <Message>
              <p>Add a driver below...</p>
            </Message>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>

        {/* Row */}
        <Grid.Row centered={true}>
          <Grid.Column width={14}>
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 

              <Form.Field>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.onFirstNameChange} />
              </Form.Field>

              <Form.Field>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.onLastNameChange} />
              </Form.Field>

              <Form.Field>
                <label>Seats Available</label>
                <input placeholder="Seats Available" type="text" value={this.state.seatsAvailable} onChange={this.onSeatsAvailable} />
              </Form.Field>

              <Button type="submit">Add</Button>
            </Form>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>

      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change `this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);` to `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`, or use fat arrow function for the function definition, which gives you lexical `this` binding.

Comment: Thank you Eric! That's the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your constructor bindings:

this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

Should most likely be:

This.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)

as all you are doing there is binding 'this' to the function.

It looks like it isn't binding so when you call 'this' in handleSubmit it is referring to the function not the component. Generally if you're seeing issues with an undefined prop it's always a good idea to try 'console.log(this)' in your function to check it is scoped correctly.